# Changing recursive function to iterative function in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I read that you can turn any recursive function into an iterative function. I have an iterative function to obtain values from the nested list shown here:

```
filled_list = [1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3,4]]]]
```

Recursive Function:

```
def recursive_list(value, count):
    x, _, _, _d = value
    if not count%2:
        yield x
    yield from ([] if not isinstance(_d, list) else recursive_list(_d, count+2))
x = recursive_list(filled_list, 0)
print(list(x), "Parsing a list recursively.")
```

Output: [1, 1, 1, 1] Parsing a list recursively.

I am trying to turn this into an iterative function. Here is what I have so far. I am stuck and don't understand how to iterate through each nested list until I reach the end. The output should be the same as the recursive function.

```
def iterative_list(value):
    value_list = []
    for a in value:
        for _d in value:
            a, _, _, _d = value
            y, _, _, _d = _d
            value_list.append(a)
            value_list.append(y)
    return value_list
z = iterative_list(filled_list)
print(z, "Parsing a list iteratively.")
```

Comment: Why would you write such a convoluted recursive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input will always follow the same pattern i.e three integers, then a list, you can simply use a `while` loop:

```
def get_first(d): 
  while isinstance(d[-1], list):
    a, *_, d = d
    yield a
  yield d[0]

print(list(get_first([1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3,4]]]])))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Timings:

```
import time

def timeit(f):
  _start = time.time()
  _ = list(f([1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2,3,4]]]]))
  print(f'{f.__name__} finished in {time.time()-_start} seconds')

@timeit
def get_first_iterative(d): 
  while isinstance(d[-1], list):
    a, *_, d = d
    yield a
  yield d[0]

@timeit
def get_first_recursive(d):
  def recursive_list(value):
     x, _, _, _d = value
     yield x
     yield from ([] if not isinstance(_d, list) else recursive_list(_d))
  return recursive_list(d)
```

Output:

```
get_first_iterative finished in 2.7894973754882812e-05 seconds
get_first_recursive finished in 1.7881393432617188e-05 seconds
```

While it appears from the timing above that the recursive solution is faster than the iterative solution, this is not the case, as a plot of the timings of each solution over data up to a depth of 100 reveals:

[image]

The source code for the plot above can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/f6d0443aa0ceb40e0f7f7f3549a6519c)

Comment: Is there a major speed difference between the two?

Comment: I guess that in this case, iteration is at least twice as fast, even after eliminating the unneeded count parameter from the recursive version.  But I suggest that you time both yourself with the timeit module.

Comment: @EvanKim Please see my recent edit. Generally in Python iteration is faster than recursion.